# How to UPDATE `table` SET the_col = current_timestamp in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

How to do this mysql query in laravel?

`UPDATE table SET the_col = current_timestamp`

Comment: thanks for the advice ^^ but I rather keep the question short cause I already searched for it but found none, but havent tried by myself yet, so i posted it first and then try by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('condition','vlaue')->update(['col1'=>'val1', 'col2'=>'val2']);
```

For more please have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#updates)

EDIT:

```
 DB::table('table_name')->update(['accept_time' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIME')]);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to use current_timestamp that mysql provided, I searched on doc and google but dont have any idea on updating by using current_timestamp value

Comment: you want to update timestamp colums like 'created_at' and updated_at?

Comment: hmm maybe? but its not always updated when it is updated? its like accept_time when it is accepted the accept_time col will be updated

Comment: okay have you tried like this.  update(['accept_time' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIME')]); Also look at my edit

Comment: Yeah that worked, Order::where('id','selected')
            ->update(['accept_time'=>DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')]); Thanks sir, for helping